# How to create array of concatenated contents from an array of labeld arrays

Tags: performance, matlab, cell-array

I have the following data:

1. a cell array of labels (e.g. a cell array of 4 options of types of messages where each type is a string)
2. an cell array of messages (e.g. a cell array of 5000 messages where each message is a cell array of many words strings).
3. an cell array of labels for each message (e.g. a cell array of 5000 strings where string in cell i is type of message in cell i in array in part 2).

My goal is to get from this data a cell array of size as of num of labels where in each cell there is concatenated contents from all the messages of type as the label (e.g. get a cell array of 4 cells where in cell i there is a cell array of all the words from all the messages that their type is i).

I implemented 3 method to perform this. This is the code for my 3 implementations:

```
%...............................................................
% setting data for tic toc tests
messagesTypesOptions = {'type1';'type2';'type3';'type4'};
messages = cell(5000,1);
for i = 1:5000
    messages{i} = {'word1';'word2';'word3';'word4';'word5';'word6';'word7';'word8';'word9';'word10'};
end
messages_labels = cell(5000,1);
for i = 1:5000
    messages_labels{i} = messagesTypesOptions{randi([1 4])};
end
%...............................................................

% start test
% method 1
type_to_msgs1 = cell(size(messagesTypesOptions,1),1);
tic
for i = 1:size(messagesTypesOptions,1)
    type_to_msgs1{i} = messages(strcmp(messages_labels,messagesTypesOptions{i}));

end
type_to_concatenated1 = cell(4,1);
for i = 1:4
    type_to_msgs1{i} = type_to_msgs1{i}';
end
for i =1:4
    label_msgs = type_to_msgs1{i};
    num_of_label_msgs = size(label_msgs,2);
    for j = 1: num_of_label_msgs
        label_msgs{j} = label_msgs{j}';
    end
    type_to_concatenated1{i} = [label_msgs{:}];
end
toc

% method 2
type_to_concatenated2 = cell(4,1);
tic
labelStr_to_labelIndex = containers.Map(messagesTypesOptions,1:4);
for textIndex = 1:5000
    type_to_concatenated2{labelStr_to_labelIndex(messages_labels{textIndex})} = ...
    [type_to_concatenated2{labelStr_to_labelIndex(messages_labels{textIndex})},...
        messages{textIndex}'];
end
toc

% method 3
type_to_concatenated3 = cell(4,1);
tic
labelStr_to_labelIndex2 = containers.Map(messagesTypesOptions,1:4);
matrix_label_to_isMsgFromLabel = zeros(4,5000);
for textIndex = 1:5000
    matrix_label_to_isMsgFromLabel(labelStr_to_labelIndex2(messages_labels{textIndex})...
    ,textIndex) = 1;
end
for i = 1:4
    label_msgs3 = messages(~~matrix_label_to_isMsgFromLabel(i,:))';
    num_of_label_msgs3 = size(label_msgs3,2);
    for j = 1: num_of_label_msgs3
        label_msgs3{j} = label_msgs3{j}';
    end
    type_to_concatenated3{i} = [label_msgs3{:}];
end
toc
```

Those are the results I get:

> Elapsed time is 0.033120 seconds.
>
> Elapsed time is 0.471959 seconds.
>
> Elapsed time is 0.095011 seconds.

So, the conclusion is that method 1 is the fastest.

Now, my question is: Is there a way to solve this in a faster way?

Intuitively, it seams that my method1 is not very efficient because it has a for loop with `strcmp` and the `strcmp` is reading all the messages, so it is reading *num of labels* times all the messages, i.e reading *num of labels (types)* the same thing.

So, is there a way to modify one of my methods to get faster solution? Is there another method which is faster?

**EDIT:** Here I used for the examples constant messages. But, I want a solution for the case that the messages are different from each other and can be of different size.

**EDIT2:**  Also, the types are strings that don't necessarily has numbers in them. (e.g. instead of type1,type2,... that I used for the example code, it can be 'error', 'warning', 'valid').

Comment: Are you sure you need the `for` loops containing `type_to_msgs1{i} = type_to_msgs1{i}';` and `label_msgs{j} = label_msgs{j}';`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have `messages` and need to index into them to get output for each cell of the output cell array and finally concatenate the elements. For indexing you can use `logical indexing` which in most cases is very efficient. For getting the logical indexing arrays, you can take help of `bsxfun`. Here's the code to wrap up the discussion -

```
%// Get the parameters
lbls_len = numel(messages_labels);
msgtypeops_len = numel(messagesTypesOptions);

%// Tag messages_labels and messagesTypesOptions with numbers
alltypes = [messages_labels ; messagesTypesOptions];
[~,~,IDs] = unique(alltypes,'stable');
lbls = IDs(1:lbls_len);
typeops = IDs(lbls_len+1:end);

%// Positions of matches for each label IDs against type IDS
pos = bsxfun(@eq,lbls,typeops');  %//'

%// Logically index into messages and select the ones based on positions
%// obtained in the previous step for the final output and finally 
%// concatenate along the rows to get us the final output cell array
out = arrayfun(@(n) vertcat(messages{pos(:,n)})',1:msgtypeops_len,'Uni',0)';
```

### Benchmarking

Here are some runtimes comparing `Method - 1` that turned out to be best one as listed in the question against the proposed solution.

1) With length of `messages_labels` as `5000`:

```
------------------ With Method - 1
Elapsed time is 0.072821 seconds.
------------------ With Proposed solution
Elapsed time is 0.053961 seconds.
```

2) With length of `messages_labels` as `500000`:

```
------------------ With Method - 1
Elapsed time is 6.998149 seconds.
------------------ With Proposed solution
Elapsed time is 2.765090 seconds.
```

An almost **`1.5x-2.5x`** speeedup might be good enough for you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My question wasn't clear enough. I edited my question. The contents of the messages are not a constant. each message can has different words and different num of words. Also, the types are strings that don't necessarily has numbers in them.

Comment: Thank you! please see my second edit I added to the question. I written it before in the comment but not in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As ever, this boils down to a simple indexing problem, and for cell arrays of strings MATLAB has a nice way to generate those indices: [`ismember`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html). There might be a clever way to then use that index vector to pull all the messages out in one go, but logical indexing is easy and quick enough, and JIT magic actually makes the trivial loop faster than `arrayfun` (using R2013b on Linux). That gives us this:

```
tic
out = cell(4,1);
[~, idx] = ismember(messages_labels, messagesTypesOptions);
for ii=1:4
    out{ii} = vertcat(messages{idx == ii})';
end
toc
```

With the above added to the end of the original code:

```
>> test
Elapsed time is 0.056497 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.857934 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.201966 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.017667 seconds.
```

Not bad :D

Replace all the 5000's with 50000's and it still scales linearly like #1 and #3:

```
>> test
Elapsed time is 0.550462 seconds.
Elapsed time is 48.685048 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.965559 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.162989 seconds.
```

Just to be sure:

```
>> isequal(type_to_concatenated1, type_to_concatenated2, type_to_concatenated3, out)

ans =

     1
```

---

And, if you can handle the grouped messages being column vectors rather than rows, take out the transpose...

```
...
    out{ii} = vertcat(messages{idx == ii});
...
```

...and it's twice as fast again:

```
>> test
Elapsed time is 0.552040 seconds.
Elapsed time is <skipped>
Elapsed time is 1.986059 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.077958 seconds.
```